Get-NetAdapter returns String in Listbox
I am currently working on a tool that is supposed to take over the IPv4 configuration, among other things. So far I have automatically determined the current adapter, with several active adapters (e.g. VM adapter at the host) the wrong one is selected.
Now I have added a ListBox where the adapter can be selected. However, i want to have the Adapter Name in the Listbox and use the Value of the selected Adapter to config New-NetIPAddress
Is there an elegant and lean solution for this?
This shows "'MSFT_NetAdapter (CreationClassName = "MSFT_NetA...." at the listbox but works fine
$getAdapter = Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.Status -eq 'Up'}

$adapterName = $getAdapter.name

foreach ($adapter in $getAdapter) {
    $listBox.Items.Add($adapter)
}


If i use foreach (... in $adapterName) then I get correct Name in Listbox but the "try" with $selectedAdapter fails of course..
function set-ip { 
    #... some var
    #... validate ip format etc.

    $selectedAdapter = $listBox.SelectedItem

    $IPParam = @{
        AddressFamily  = $ipType
        IPAddress      = $ipv4
        PrefixLength   = $prefix
        DefaultGateway = $gateway
    }
    $DNSParam = @{
        ServerAddresses = @($DNS1, $DNS2)
    }
    Write-Host "ok select here now"
    if ($selectedAdapter) {
        try {
            Write-Host "set ip for $selectedAdapter"

       
            If (($selectedAdapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration).IPv4Address.IPAddress) {
                $selectedAdapter | Remove-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily $ipType -Confirm:$false
            }
            If (($selectedAdapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration).Ipv4DefaultGateway) {
                $selectedAdapter | Remove-NetRoute -AddressFamily $ipType -Confirm:$false
            }

            $selectedAdapter | New-NetIPAddress @IPParam -Confirm:$false
            $selectedAdapter | Set-DnsClientServerAddress @DNSParam -Confirm:$false
            Write-Host "some text"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "some warning text"
            Write-Warning "$_"
        }
    }
}


Please format your post properly.
